# Lync SDK (Microsoft.Lync.Model)

Tags: lync, lync-client-sdk

Im Orkhan Aliyev lead engineer at SchwaTech LLC from Azerbaijan. At The moment we are working on a device per request of a customer. This device would have to connect to skype for business or lync and synchronise some user details to an LCD screen on it. The device communicates with PC via USB cable. So far we were able to implement all the requirements using Lync SDK (Microsoft.Lync.Model) library except 2. Missed call and missed IM. We need to highlight missed IM and / or missed call icons on the screen whenever these events occur and hide those once there are no missed items. We have tried many things for weeks now but can't seem to wrap our heads around these obstacles.  Could you please guide us on how to implement these two ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get this information using the Lync Client SDK.  There is some hidden COM API's that look like they may work, but they don't.

The only thing I would suggest is that you move away from the Lync Client SDK as it hasn't been updated in awhile and is slowly breaking against the latest Skype for Business client.

I would suggest moving to the [UCWA web sdk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/unifiedcommunicationswebapi2_0).  You can then use the [conversationLogs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/conversationlogs_ref) to implement your missed IM / Calls feature.